# Tkinter: How do I bind to the state that activefill uses for a polygon on a canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a custom button using a canvas with a polygonal shape drawn to it. I've set the polygon to have a special activefill color and indeed it works, switching colors *only* when the mouse pointer is within the actual polygon's boundary (not just anywhere on the canvas).

That said, while I can bind to `<Enter>` and `<Leave>`, these apply to the entire canvas, not just within the polygon (where activefill color toggles). **What do I bind to so I can trigger on the same state activefill does, leveraging the in-or-out calculation already done to that polygon by Tk itself?**

Edit: As always, I did quite a bit of searching before submitting this question (and oddly, search on stackoverflow kept coming up completely empty today) and it was not clear that one needs to use tag_bind instead of bind to accomplish this in particular. Hopefully this Q&A will help others who search for "bind", "activefill" and "state" (and "create_polygon", and several other terms) in pursuit of this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would bind to the `<Enter>` and leave event, but you should use the [tag_bind](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.tag_bind-method) method on the canvas rather than the `bind` method. `tag_bind` lets you set bindings on individual items on the canvas, or on groups of items that share the same tag.

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted but I looked all over for this and couldn't find the answer. Anyway, thank you - switching to tag_bind did the job, and may help greatly simplify the design of what I was working on as well! :-)

Comment: @MartyMacGyver: the tooltip of the down-vote button says "does not show any research effort", and your question shows no research effort beyond "I tried one thing".

Comment: Considering I tried some fifty different searches that came up empty (including on here), based on the keywords that seemed relevant, it wasn't "one thing". Again, I appreciate the answer - it was not at all obvious that tag_bind was required for this.

Comment: @MartyMacGyver: If that's true, you should include it in your question. Sharing your research helps others.

Comment: Yes, it's true: I searched (Google), and searching stackoverflow (e.g., on "activefill bind"), was not resulting in anything (now it does though - this very question is the result... if such a question matching these keywords had been asked and answered before anywhere I looked, I'd never have posted this in the first place).